# Htaccess: remove .php and redirect to custom 404 page

Tags: .htaccess

**htaccess:**

```
# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Redirect to 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

This works and all requests redirect to the custom 404 page, for example:

```
localhost/dashboard.html
localhost/dashboard.gg
localhost/dashboard.anything
```

but .php redirects to the default 404 page and not to my custom 404 page

```
localhost/dashboard.php => default 404 page by apache
```

I know there is a mistake in **[R=404]** but i do not know how to fix it. Will anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

By default  `- [R=404]` redirects not-found requests to the default error page of web hosting service provider. You can use the Uri of your custom error page as the substitution string in your rule to change this behaviour.

```
# Redirect to 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* /my404.php  [L,R]
```

Comment: It does not work, it still throws the default 404 page

Comment: Ok I have removed  `R=404` flag from the rule. Try the updated version.